# getting error while using phpoffice_Excel laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.2` and I try using this package : https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Here is my code :

```
Excel::load('path to file\stlist.xlsx', function($reader) {

    // reader methods

});
```

but getting this error :

> Class 'PHPExcel_Calculation' not found

Comment: can you upload your controller screenshot

Comment: PHPExcel_Calculation where did you get this class, if you setup perfectly as it shows on that URL then you will use like this in the controller :
use Excel;